# What does this notation mean? It is two numbers in brackets

Tags: piano, notation, fingering

I originally though they were (rather bad) fingering suggestions, but then I saw the second bar where the fingering suggestion is 2 4, yet this (51) still shows. What exactly does it mean then when the numbers are in brackets like this? My music theory book does not explain fingering notation at all for some reason, and Wikipedia is not helping here either.

[image]

Comment: I would just stop at "(rather bad) fingering suggestions". Somebody ought to tell whoever thought those fingerings were sensible why pianos have sustain pedals!

Comment: @alephzero I am glad I am not the only one who thought that. I have already ignored their previous suggestions and I think I shall continue.

Comment: You can't use a sustain peddle here ( don't think), else you mung the right hand.  That said I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @coteyr I think sustain is necessary here, though I reapply the pedal at the third bass note.

Comment: This really does not look like fingering to me.  It might make some sense for the first bar but not for the second.  Are there more examples of this notation in the piece?  The next bar doesn't have (50) under the first note by any chance does it?

Comment: @JimM Page 3 @ http://hz.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/b/b2/IMSLP72131-PMLP02774-Schumann--Davidsbundler-Op6--2nd-ver--Ed-B_H.pdf

Comment: @bwv869 Thanks for the link.  This notation is used in a number of places throughout the pieces.  There are some places where it seems to make sense to me.  I think what is confusing me is that it is inconsistent.  If there are three notes to play I would expect to see fingering for all three;  in some cases they are showing fingering for just the lowest note or the lower two notes (at least I think that's what they are doing).

Answer (score 18):

In piano this **parenthesis** with 2 fingering means that you should change finger while keeping the note played.

For example at the second bar you show, you should first use your 5th finger to attack the note, and switch to your 1st finger while keeping the note played, so you can reach the next note (that is quite far) with your 5th finger.

Comment: I always thought that was notated like https://musescore.org/sites/musescore.org/files/fingersubstitution.jpg